# Hi,. I want ssms query (SQL query)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want ssms query (SQL query) which will help me in getting YTD data. 
Example if I am in Jan month then take Jan data and create column to add month=1,
if I am in feb month then take Jan + feb and month column=2. 
Which means when I will in feb I will  get Jan with month=1 and Jan+ feb with month=2. And so on...

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you - [mcve].

Comment: Your question needs sample data and desired reults.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT will be able to add months together for you, here's a query I ran on my crime database recently, you can change as needed:

```
--returns the total of all 2019
select      LGA, ([Jan-2019] + [Feb-2019] + [Mar-2019] + [Apr-2019] + [May-2019] + [Jun-2019] + [Jul-2019] + [Aug-2019] + [Sep-2019] + [Oct-2019] + [Nov-2019] + [Dec-2019])
FROM        Crime_LGA
```

alternatively, you can make a new column for each MTD, or maybe even a new table.  Here's some code i used recently to add columns:

```
--to add a total 2019 column
ALTER TABLE Crime_Suburb
ADD         Total_2010 int NOT NULL DEFAULT (0),

--to add values to the column
UPDATE      Crime_Suburb
SET         Total_2010 =  ([Jan-2010] + [Feb-2010] + [Mar-2010] + [Apr-2010] + [May-2010] + [Jun-2010] + [Jul-2010] + [Aug-2010] + [Sep-2010] + [Oct-2010] + [Nov-2010] + [Dec-2010])
FROM        Crime_Suburb
```